# In Canada, can tuition paid by an RESP withdrawal be claimed on the income tax return?

Tags: canada, income-tax, tax-deduction, resp, tuition

Can tuition fees be claimed on the tax return if the money was withdrawn from an RESP we've been contributing to?

Answer (score 3):

There is no document that I know of that stipulates otherwise. This can also be corroborated by the fact that RESP withdrawals are considered as income in the name of the student. Thus, so long as the student pays tuition and receives a T2202A slip from the educational institution, they should be able to claim tuition, education, and textbook amounts.